# Populate ListBox object from a list of custom objects

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of Backup objects (a class I made) how can I bind the ListBox to my list of Backup objects so if I remove/modify/insert the list of backups then the ListBox is also updated automatically?

I've done this in C++(qt) by using models, however, I'm new to C# and can't find the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a `List<t>` use a `BindingList<t>`

Set your listbox's DataSource property to your BindingList instance
Set the  listbox's DisplayMember to a property you want to see in the list

Items added/removed should update your listbox.

Here's an example with the DGV

```
BindingList<Employee> employees = new BindingList<Employee>();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var emp = new Employee { FirstName = "fn" + i, LastName = "ln" + i, EmployeeId = i };
            employees.Add(emp);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = employees;
    }
}class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

With this I get the following result in my DGV

[image]

Comment: Great! Can I also use a BindingList for a DataGridView ? how would I bind the different columns? Thanks

Comment: did you try it? Just drop a DGV on your form and set it's datasource to that same collection and see what happens. The only difference is, you won't specify display members like you did in a single column listbox.

Comment: hmmm, can you edit your question and show the code involved? With a BindingList you should have just been able to drag a DGV on the form and set it's datasource to your BindingList. Multiple properties should become columns of the row.

Comment: You're right, I was assigning the listbox as the datasource!. Thanks

Comment: Wow, just saw your updated answer, thanks again for the details!